# How to use concat with lambda and ObservableSource

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

```
RxJava2
kotlin
```

This works ok and I can concat 2 observables

```
   Observable.concat(countries(), animals())
                    .subscribeBy {
                        println(it)
                    }
```

This the sample I can't understand as it use a lambda that seems to take a ObservableSource and I want to concat the 2 observables, but it results in a null exception. Just wondering what I am doing wrong with this. And what is the purpose to use a lambda with the concat?

```
        Observable.concat<String> {
                    it.onNext(countries())
                    it.onNext(animals())
                }.subscribeBy {
                    println(it)
                }


    private fun animals(): Observable<String> =
            Observable.just("fox", "cat", "dog", "bear", "bat", "hare", "lion", "tiger")

    private fun countries(): Observable<String> =
            Observable.just("England", "France", "Thailand", "America", "Scotland", "Ice Land")
```

This is the crash I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableConcatMap$SourceObserver.onNext(ObservableConcatMap.java:129)
```

This is the interface for the `ObservableSource` I think I am referring to.

```
public interface ObservableSource<T> {
    void subscribe(@NonNull Observer<? super T> observer);
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Passing a lambda to concat resolves to [`concat(ObservableSource<? extends ObservableSource<? extends T>> sources)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html#concat-io.reactivex.ObservableSource-). Because `ObservableSource` is an interface with a single non-default method, this triggers Kotlin's [SAM conversion](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#sam-conversions).  This is why it picks that overload - it's the only one with an interface that can be fulfilled with SAM conversion.

Thus, the lambda is an implementation of the [`ObservableSource.subscribe(Observer<? super T> observer)`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/ObservableSource.html#subscribe-io.reactivex.Observer-) method.  That method is documented as:

> Subscribes the given Observer to this ObservableSource instance.

Thus, the lambda needs to subscribe the parameter (`it`) to the source of `Observables`.  You're getting a `NullPointerException` because rather than subscribing it, you begin calling `onNext` on an `Observer` that's not yet subscribed, and thus has the incorrect internal state (in this case, there's a queue that's not set up yet, but that's not especially important).

To fulfill the method's contract, you would simply create an `Observable` that emits `Observable`s and subscribe `it` (the `Observer`) to that `Observable` in the lambda, like so:

```kotlin
Observable.concat<String> {
    Observable.just(countries(), animals()).subscribe(it)
}.subscribeBy {
    println(it)
}
```

I've tested this locally and it produces the expected result.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just wondering why we need to subscribe twice. When testing the `subscribeBy {println(it)}` is never called

Comment: You're subscribing twice because there are two different observers - one that subscribes to the Observable that emits _other_ `Observables` in order to concatenate them, and a second one that subscribes to the concatenated emissions (the `String`s).  Could you clarify what you mean by "When testing the `subscribeBy {println(it)}` is never called"?  The `println` is definitely called - it prints all the values - and the `subscribeBy` also must be called in order for the `println` to be subscribed.

Comment: Is there anything else you can do in lambda? Just a quick question

Comment: What do you mean by that?  Lambdas in general, or in the lambda passed to concat?  Lambdas in general: Anything that takes a type subject to SAM conversion.  The lambda passed to concat: You could put any code you want, but it must subscribe the parameter to an `Observable` of `Observable`s to get the expected result.  You could dynamically generate that `Observable`, though, hence the ability to have a block of code.